# Regroup dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

With the dataset below:

```
  id from to trip
1  1    A  B <NA>
2  1    B  C    X
3  1    C  D <NA>
4  1    D  A    X
5  2    B  A    X
6  2    A  C <NA>
7  2    C  D <NA>
```

I'm trying to split the data whenever I reach an X on the trip column, in order to obtain something like this(note that there's a new column):

```
  id from to trip group
1  1    A  B <NA>  1
2  1    B  C    X  1
3  1    C  D <NA>  2
4  1    D  A    X  2
5  2    B  A    X  3
6  2    A  C <NA>  4
7  2    C  D <NA>  4
```

What this means is that it goes through the observations/rows, and based on the id and trip column, it starts a new number every time it reaches an X.

I've tried a couple of things with `group_by(df, id, trip)`, but I always end up without a similar structure to that one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pending on how many rows you have, you could always just create a new variable that auto increments every time an x is present.

Comment: Primitive solution, but easy to implement.

Comment: `mutate(df, cumsum(!is.na(trip)))`? Or just `group_by(df,  cumsum(!is.na(trip)))`

Comment: @Lowpar, on this example it is simple, but in real life I have 9.000.000 observations, which makes it more complicated to take a basic approach. And what you're mentioning is it with an if function?

Comment: @Axeman, I tried that as well, but what happens is that it increments a new number whenever it finds X, when it actually should be only after that. Meaning that finding an X should still give the same number as the previous row.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira Add `lag`.

Comment: @Axeman Works perfectly. It still takes quite a while to calculate everything but better than nothing. At least I have the count.

Comment: @Axeman just out of curiosity, how would your mutate function lookalike if instead of an NA value I would have a factor with a space?
I have this `mutate(travel_by, trip_id = c( 1, head(cumsum((trip == "X")) +1, -1)))` , but I'm not sure if there's something more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

This base R method works for the example:

```
df$group <- c(1, head(cumsum(df$trip == "X") + 1, -1))
```

In the example, it returns

```
df
  id from to trip group
1  1    A  B <NA>     1
2  1    B  C    X     1
3  1    C  D <NA>     2
4  1    D  A    X     2
5  2    B  A    X     3
6  2    A  C <NA>     4
7  2    C  D <NA>     4
```

Also, in the case that the first observation is "X", then 1 will be the first element and 2 will be the second element, which I believe is what is desired.

As @manotheshark mentions in the commments, this solution will not work on NA values, because `cumsum` will return NA after the first NA is encountered. The suggested solution would be to replace `df$trip == "X"` with `is.na(df$trip)` which will return the correct values in the presence of NAs.

Comment: This doesn't work if the trip is stored as `NA` and not as text as `cumsum` will return `NA`. A slight modification will address this: `df$group <- c(1, head(cumsum(!is.na(df$trip)) + 1, -1))`

Comment: Actually this solves another problem I have when instead of having NA, I have factors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if you actually need to start new group on row **after** X i think you can achieve that with another shift() on the trip == "X":

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

na.zero <- function (x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}

dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 from = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 6, replace = T),
                 to = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 6, replace = T),
                 trip = sample(c("X", NA), 6, replace = T))

dt[, group:=(cumsum(na.zero(trip=="X"))+cumsum(id-na.zero(shift(id, 1L,type = 'lag'))))]

   id from to trip group
1:  1    B  D   NA     1
2:  1    B  C    X     2
3:  1    C  C   NA     2
4:  2    D  A    X     4
5:  2    A  A   NA     4
6:  2    D  A   NA     4
```